# Minimal prime ideal and normalness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and   $Min(R)$ the
set of all minimal prime ideals of $R$. When cinsidering $Min (R) $  as a
subspace of $Spec(R)$ with respect to the zariski topolog, it is
well-known that $Min(R)$ has a clopen basis and hence it is
completely regular. It was written in an informal text, without any references, that  this space is Normal. Why is this true?